# Cannot run ./configure from source code

Tags: apt, bash, compiling, source-code

I downloaded the latest coreutils source code (coreutils-9.1.tar.xz) from https://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/coreutils/ to slightly modify the output of the `ls` command to simply print *Hello there you beautiful people!* every time the command is issued. After decompressing the archive and navigating the directories as in `coreutils-9.1/src/` I proceed to edit the `ls.c` file using the nano editor. I just insert `printf("Hello there you beautiful people! \n");` on the first line in the `main` funciton. After saving the file and returning to the `coreutils-9.1` directory I must configre the **gcc compiler** running either `./configure` or `bash configure`. I was able to do it the first time and a `Makefile` is generated to which I issue the `make` command followed by `sudo make install`. Now, every time the `ls` command is called, *Hello there you beautiful people!* is displayed on the terminal screen.

The problem is I have not been able to reverse this because every time I try to run the `bash configure` command I get this error.

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
  alias in your environment
configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
```

I then downloaded the *xeyes* source code found in the *x11-apps* package issuing `sudo apt-get source x11-apps`. Same deal, I navigate to the directory where the **configure** bash script is and I issue the `bash configure` command and I'm met with *the same error*. This then, must mean I'm unable to configure any source code I download since I did not mess around with the *xeyes* source code and has nothing to do with the `ls` command.

Returning to the `coreutils-9.1` directory I open the **config.log** file and find the error message and the line it originated from inside the **configure** file

```
configure:5090: looking for aux files: config.rpath config.guess config.sub compile missing install-sh
configure:5103:  trying ./build-aux/
configure:5132:   ./build-aux/config.rpath found
configure:5132:   ./build-aux/config.guess found
configure:5132:   ./build-aux/config.sub found
configure:5132:   ./build-aux/compile found
configure:5132:   ./build-aux/missing found
configure:5114:   ./build-aux/install-sh found
configure:5268: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:5341: result: /usr/local/bin/install -c
configure:5352: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:5388: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
  alias in your environment
configure:5404: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
```

I then open the **configure** file with nano and navigate to line number **5388** and find this

```
     if test "$*" != "X $srcdir/configure conftest.file" \
        && test "$*" != "X conftest.file $srcdir/configure"; then

        # If neither matched, then we have a broken ls.  This can happen
        # if, for instance, CONFIG_SHELL is bash and it inherits a
        # broken ls alias from the environment.  This has actually
        # happened.  Such a system could not be considered "sane".
        as_fn_error $? "ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
  alias in your environment" "$LINENO" 5
```

I have another Virutal Machine with Ubuntu 21.04 in which I'm able to do this with no problem at all. This VM has Ubuntu 22.04
I don't what to do or how to proceed. Hope I made myself as clear as possible to what I did and what I'm trying to do.

P.D.
This is my first post. I hope to have followed rules and conventions.

Comment: Did you install the modified `ls` executable to `/bin` (or `/usr/bin`) or to `/usr/local/bin`? If the latter, it may be as simple as adjusting the `PATH` so that the configure script finds the unmolested one. If the former, then you can likely simply re-install your system's default `coreutils` package from the repository.

Comment: So my first try would be `PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH" ./configure`

Comment: I was suggesting you **run** `PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH" ./configure` (that is, run `./configure` with `PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"` in its environment) - **not** to add it to your .bashrc file

Comment: This worked. How do I mark my question as solved?